# How do you validate a number field that is read only in html?

Tags: html, forms

I have a number field and it is read-only as it is auto filled but if this number is negative, it should not accept the value however, it is.

My view:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Admin time (minutes):</label>
  <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="admin_time"   class="form-control @error('admin_time') is-invalid @enderror" id="admin_time" min="0"  step="1" onkeydown="return false;" readonly required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use "disabled" instead of "readonly". disabled element isnt fetchable.
and second way - use JS or PHP for avoiding this field (as there are 2 languages you'll need to do it yourself sadly + i dont know all form fields...)